# Background image gets cut off when animating horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a parallax effect on my website, but when I apply a horizontal animation, the image is getting cut off. How do I fix this so that the image either loops/repeats, or actually just show the rest of the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVpq1.png) as the user scrolls down.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/avphan/pen/XWdYoxJ). This is what I'm kinda trying to do: [parallax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0evRWKr6t4).

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Alex Phan</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parallax-container">
            <div class="ocean-sky layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -100"></div>
            <div class="s-clouds layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="m-clouds layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="l-clouds layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="bg-trees layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="fg-trees layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="grass layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -200" data-lax-translate-x="0 0, 7000 (15*vh) | loop=7000"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="categories-container lax"  data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -300">
            <div class="about">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lax.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    color: black;
    /* background-color: #2e2823; */
    background-color: #79caf9;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parallax-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow: ;
}

.layer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.ocean-sky {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/sky-ocean.png");
}

.s-clouds {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/small-clouds.png");
}

.m-clouds {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/medium-clouds.png");
}

.l-clouds {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/large-clouds.png");
}

.bg-trees {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/bg-trees.png");
}

.fg-trees {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/fg-trees.png");
}

.grass {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("../images/grass.png");
}

.categories-container {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #151315;
}

.about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.about h1 {
    font-family: calibri;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    lax.setup() // init

    const updateLax = () => {
        lax.update(window.scrollY)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateLax)
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateLax)
}
```

Comment: with background images, you may want to instead of translating X (which is the container  div) translate the `background-position` x position.  Not sure if you can do that but probably (with css).  at a glance, it looks like the parallax library your using may not support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like https://github.com/alexfoxy/lax.js *does* support what you need.

Here for the grass, change your lax translate from `data-lax-translate-x` to  `data-lax-bg-pos-x` and you're on your way!  You might want that for all background images that need to slide left to right.

```html
<div class="grass layer lax" 
   data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -200" 
   data-lax-bg-pos-x="0 0, 7000 (15*vh) | loop=7000"></div>
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much. I've literally been experimenting different CSS properties for the past week and couldn't get it. Guess I need to read the lax documentation better. Thank you again. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to try to play with the `width, left, and background-size` css rules to get this work.

So quickly:

- set the grass div width to a large enough number that the edge won't ever reveal itself when scrolling. If you set width to say 400% to make it really wide, then use the `Left` to drag it back. I set `left: -300%;` to move all excess to the left side of screen.
- The background image will stretch 400% times also from the width. So to compensate for that, the background image will be 100% / 4 (width is 100% * 4, so inverse that equation) to keep the aspect ratio of the original image. So `width: 400%`, and  `background-size: 25% 100%`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    lax.setup() // init

    const updateLax = () => {
        lax.update(window.scrollY)
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateLax)
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateLax)
}
```

```css
body {
    color: black;
    /* background-color: #2e2823; */
    background-color: #79caf9;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parallax-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.ocean-sky {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/dRNsTvA.png");
}

.s-clouds {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/cLFED08.png");
}

.m-clouds {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/ggR1pJX.png");
}

.l-clouds {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/ZCcbGfH.png");
}

.bg-trees {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/7dC1bzO.png");
}

.fg-trees {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/U5fNrqg.png");
}

.grass {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/mTiG92i.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 400%;
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  left: -300%;
}

.categories-container {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #151315;
}

.about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.about h1 {
    font-family: calibri;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Alex Phan</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parallax-container">
            <div class="ocean-sky layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -100"></div>
            <div class="s-clouds layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="m-clouds layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="l-clouds layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="bg-trees layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="fg-trees layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -175"></div>
            <div class="grass layer lax" data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -200" data-lax-translate-x="0 0, 7000 (15*vh) | loop=7000"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="categories-container lax"  data-lax-translate-y="0 1, 400 -300">
            <div class="about">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lax.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I really appreciate it. I better understand how the css rules work in regards to left, background-size, etc.